# Pygments in wxPython?

Tags: python, syntax, wxpython, highlighting, pygments

Is it at all possible to use Pygments inside of wxPython to provide syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Positive. While pygments is originally aimed at CSS output, you can define a pygments formatter to define styles for a wx.StyledTextCtrl for example. I happen to have done that just recently:

http://relet.net/frog/archives/170